# Recover Variances From GLS Model (Phylogenetic Least Squares on Evolutionary Tree)

Tags: r, time-series, variance, covariance, generalized-least-squares

I don't know how to calculate the variance of a variable when all of its observations have an arbitrary correlation structure.

I am simulating the evolution of animals as they branch apart into different species and form
an evolutionary tree.  Specifically, I am modelling the evolution of two (though I want to extend to three) traits which evolve across the phylogenetic tree via Brownian motion.  More closely related species which have been evolving in the same lineage for a longer time before splitting apart will have more covariance in their evolved trait values.  A common approach  in the field (called phylogenetic least squares) is to do a generalized least squares regression where we fix the values of trait X and use the amount of shared evolutionary history to create a correlation matrix of the Y traits which we use as the error matrix in a GLS analysis.

The beta result I get from the regression is correct, and when I multiply it by the variance I used in simulating the data, I do get the value for the covariance value I used.  However, I can't figure out how to get the variance of either trait from my regression results.  I have been playing around with 5 parameters: (1) The amount of time the traits have been evolving (the variance of a Brownian motion process is the length of time multiplied with the variance of the process) (2) The Error Correlation Matrix fed into the GLS (3) The beta of the two regressions: X on Y and Y on X. (4) Sigma(model): which I think is the residual standard deviation for both regressions X on Y and Y on X. (5) the variance-covariance matrix for a fitted model `vcov(model)` (in R programming language).  Which I'm not sure what this is, but it says: "A matrix of the estimated covariances between the parameter estimates in the linear or non-linear predictor of the model."  I think it might be the measured variance of the independent variable, in which case it systematically underestimates it probably because it assumes the X don't covary with Y but instead cause it.

So in summary, with the 5 parameter results I get from a typical GLS fit, I cannot calculate the original variance of the data.  Multiplying the residual standard deviation by beta does give a biassed estimate of of the covariance.  And averaging the two biassed estimates from X on Y and Y on X gives a less biassed covariance estimate.  But I can't recover the actual variances of either variable.

I would greatly appreciate an explanation too if the answer is that this is impossible to do.  Part of what I don't understand is idea of converting from a multivariate normal distribution which I generated my data with to a regression where... do we assume a direction in the regression, that X causes Y and therefore X has no error? And therefore we underestimate it's true variance if it actually had error? But how did generating X and Y from a multivariate normal distribution give X error to begin with?

Thank you!